# $q.all() not calling fail handler if one promise fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Just trying to understand how the `$q.all()` works:

In my example, i use `$q.all()` to execute 2 functions (both intentionally return `reject()` ), i expected the `fail` handler in the `then()` to get called, but it doesnt, why is this so?

**Code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope,$q) {


    f1 = function(){
        return $q.defer().reject();
    }

    f2 = function(){
        return $q.defer().reject();
    }
    s = function(){alert('success!'); };
    f = function(){alert('failed!');};
    $q.all([f1(),f2()]).then(s,f);
}
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/ADukg/10942/

---

**EDIT :**

I found the same code works if I make the functions return the raw promise and introduce a delay before rejecting it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/y28khhe4/1/)

Comment: your edited code should work even without the timeout. also note, you could chain with catch: `$q.all([f1(), f2()]).then(s).catch(f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
   f2 = function(){
      var p = $q.defer();
      p.reject();
      return p.promise;
    }
```

or

```
f2 = function() {
 return $q.reject()
}
```